# How to reverse Gridview Layout to ensure latest post is on top?

Tags: android-studio, gridview, reverse

I retrieve data from firebase and put it into recycler view and card view. The issue is that I can't seem to set the latest post to be on top even though I have tried using:

> LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new
>   LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
>   mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

Does not work cause its for linear

or

> GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new
>   GridLayoutManager(getActivity());
>   mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

getActivity cannot apply to GridManager for some reason. I have tried getContext or this too but there is still an error : no suitable constructor found for GridLayoutManager(FragmentActivity)

How can I go ahead doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-46-how-to-reverse-recyclerview-by-adding-items-f32db1e36c51)?

Comment: @tomerpacific yup, I have tried that and listed it out above, but it doesnt work for Grid Layout

Comment: you didn't use this line : ```mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);```

Comment: It doesnt work because its for linear. And even if I changed it to 
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity()); , nothing below will work because the getActivity cannot apply to GridManager for some reason. I have tried getContext or this too but there is still an error : no suitable constructor found for GridLayoutManager(FragmentActivity)